# d'Alembertian operator in presence of torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, differentiation

Consider a Riemann-Cartan 4-dimensional spacetime with torsion. In such a spacetime, I have been asked to compute the d'Alembertian operator acting on a scalar field. Here's what I tried:

$$ g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu} \phi = g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\left(\partial_{\nu} \phi\right) \\ = g^{\mu \nu}\left(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi -\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}(g)\partial_{\alpha}\phi + K^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}\phi\right) \\ = g^{\mu \nu}\left(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi -\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}\phi \right) $$

In the last line, contorsion tensor does not survive as it is antisymmetric. Is this correct? Then is it safe to say that this operator is not sensitive to the torsion in the spacetime?

Comment: Yes, torsion is proportional to the antisymmetric (in the last two indices) part of the connection symbols, hence the box operator acting on a scalar function is the same as for the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: Yes, your calculation and conclusion seem correct.